# Using Audio in Android, what do I do with "context"?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play an audio file using the code below. I have the audio fileset p and everything is goo except for where it says context.context comes up in red so how do i `fix that or what am I suppoesed to put in there to make the snippet of code work. Any and all help is appreciated and thanks in advance. BTW i am using android studio if that helps.

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out all i have to replace context with is "this" so the code is like below. Leaving this up in case someone in the future needs it.

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: its more important to know _why_ `this` works, and what role `Context` plays in general. Do look into this when you get a chance.